# How to fix the warnings

Tags: iphone, warnings

In my iPhone project, I am getting "method name not found", "multiple methods named 'method_name' found" warning message.

```
// in TestFirst.h
-(void) testMethod:(int)a;

// in TestFirst.m
TestSecond *ts = [[TestSecond alloc] init];
ts.delegate = self;

// in TestSecond.h
id delegate;

// in TestSecond.m
[delegate testMethod: 5]; // Warning: method name not found
```

How to resolve this kind of warnings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a precise type for the delegate:

```
TestFirst *delegate;
```

Or you can create a protocol:

```
@protocol SomeDelegate
- (void) testMethod: (int) a;
@end

@interface TestFirst : NSObject <SomeDelegate> {…}
@end

@interface TestSecond : NSObject
@property(assign) id <SomeDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Or you can keep the dynamic typing and import the correct headers:

```
@interface TestSecond : NSObject {…}
@property(assign) id delegate;
@end

#import "TestFirst.h" // or AVAudioPlayer or whatever
@implementation TestSecond

- (void) somewhere {
    [delegate testMethod:5];
}
```

Comment: Some time I will use the delegate to play a music. like [delegate play]; delegate => AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: I have used like "@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate"

Comment: I am getting same warnings If I use "@property (assign) id delegate"

Comment: Did you import the header `TestFirst.h` in your `TestSecond.m`? The compiler has to know that such method exists somewhere.

Comment: Yes i have imported the required header files.

Comment: In that case I’d like to see the full code, shortened to the [smallest working sample](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How to resolve "multiple methods named 'method_name' found" warning ?

Comment: You can pick a better, more unique name for your methods. You can also import less headers so that the compiler does not see the methods with similar names, if that’s an option.

Answer (score 0):

It might not being the best way to do it but i've seen most people using delegates using the following pattern :

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(yourMethod)]) {
     [delegate performSelector:@selector(yourMethod)];
}
```

You can add arguments using performSelector:withObject: and there are also methods allowing you to perform the selector in other threads.

You won't have any errors if you declare your delegate like

```
id delegate;
```

or

```
NSObject<DelegateProtocol> * delegate;
```